# Passing parameters to a PHP page so it can execute, but not display the PHP page

Tags: php, html

I have some basic html code on a page.
Is there a way (in HTML only), to call my PHP page, pass it parameters, but not display the PHP page?
My intent is to just send the parameters to the PHP code for it to execute, but it cannot display the PHP page.

Thanks for any ideas.
PS: This html page is very basic and does not allow scripts or Javascript, etc. Just HTML.

Rich

Comment: **No** you can't, html is a static language, means it doesn't do anything except "show" the design, to pass parameters to another page you need js/ajax it will do the jop

Comment: @jeroen, i think he wants html only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `<img>` tag for this:

```
<img src="path/to/page.php?param1=hacky&param2=solution" width="1" height="1" />
```

Comment: or js,css .... nasty but workabel    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/page.php?param1=hacky&param2=solution">`

Comment: @nogad, `PS: This html page is very basic and does not allow scripts or Javascript, etc. Just HTML.` - OP

Comment: @xYuri it does not need to run js

Comment: Here is my line. 
<img src="http://www.richtemen.com/adtracker.php?loc=North Scottsdale&amp;ad_title=Troon Homes for Sale&amp;ad_src=BackPage" width="1" height="1" />
When run, it just shows a little broken picture and does not call my php.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. My line does indeed have the HTTP:// in it.

<img src="http://www.richtemen.com/adtracker.php?loc=North Scottsdale&amp;ad_title=Troon Homes for Sale&amp;ad_src=BackPage" width="1" height="1" />

Still only produces broken image icon.

Comment: When I paste the line into the text area here, it shows the HTTP://.
But after submitting it, it being stripped out.

Comment: you need to return a valid image (and headers) as well as run the code

Comment: @rtemen Check your web server logs maybe? From my POV it is calling your PHP as I get an HTTP 200 code for that URL with this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vapo51z5/

Comment: And if you don't want to return 1x1 transparent gif with your adtracker page to get rid of the broken image icon then try @nogad suggestion of using the `<link>` tag.

Comment: Or you can add `style="display:none;" ` to the `<img>` tag to hide it.

Comment: Good Morning Everyone.  Thanks for all of the assistance.  I want to describe what I am trying to do, so that maybe someone else has done this and knows the answer.
I have an ad in BackPage. In the HTML, I have the text of the ad as well as some pictures and a link to my site to go to my page for the detailed information.
 I am also unable to send back from my PHP file the header and the blank pic because it complains that I cannot make additional changes to the header.

Well, there you have it.  Perhaps someone is knowledgable with the BackPage and how to solve this.
Thanks,
Rich